# Where can I find PayPal API documentation for C#?

Tags: c#, paypal

I can get PAYPAL API documentation that allows people on my site to pay through PAYPAL C#

This is only an example...

```
curl -v -X POST https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment \
```

Comment: By going to the website of paypal and reading the documentation. Whow.

Answer (score 2):

v1/payments is older, there is a newer v2/orders API you should check out instead

Your question is rather short on details, but there is a .NET v2 Checkout SDK available here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/rest-sdks/

The front end would look like this: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server , which does fetch( XHR calls to a server to set up and capture a transaction

More information on the server-side portion of the integration: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/reference/server-integration/setup-sdk/